# LazyH/VStack isn't lazy unless embedded in a ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui

Both LazyHStack and VStack are great for lazily loading views on demand. I noticed however that unless those views are embedded in a `ScrollView`, the lazy behavior disappears and they act like their non-lazy counterpart.

The following example shows that the views don't load lazily:

```swift
LazyHStack {
    ForEach(0..<1000) { index in
        Text("\(index)")
            .onAppear(perform: {
                 print(index)
             })
    }
}
```

All the index print out, regardless of being on screen or not. If I embed it in a scrollview, then the views start loading lazy.

Is there any way to achieve lazy behavior with a `LazyHStack` without the use of a `ScrollView`?

Comment: It is called Lazy not because it will be initialized "lazily" , but because it shows your Views "lazily" when scrolling. In SwiftUI thay basically call Reusable Views -  Lazy Views

Comment: Then that's a terrible name because something called LazyHStack should be lazy in and of itself, without the additional of a scrolling view.